# Cakefile not requiring *.coffee files

Tags: coffeescript, cakefile

I have the following files:

Cakefile:

```
require './test'
```

test.coffee:

```
console.log 'hi'
```

another_test.coffee:

```
require './test'
```

If I run cake, I get the following exception:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './test'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jose/Desktop/Cakefile:2:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jose/Desktop/Cakefile:4:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

However, if I run coffee another_test.coffee, I get this output:

```
hi
```

I installed node using brew and coffee-script using npm, and am using the following versions:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.24
$ npm -v
1.3.21
$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.7.1
```

Why can't Cakefile require test.coffee?

Comment: I think it's because of node not being able to require .coffee files (as cake is a .js script itself), so I've opened a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677931/node-not-requiring-coffee-files

Answer (score 3):

Solved by adding:

```
require 'coffee-script/register'
```

on top of Cakefile. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21678007/347915

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an absolute path ? Try this instead :

```
  require "#{__dirname}/test"
```

Comment: Thx, no luck, same error. Also, Cakefile is able to require a ./test.js file, so it doesn't look like a path problem, more like an extension thing.